# Initialize multiple variables as records in postgresql stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure where I declare three variables as records and initialize them later as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateUnitPrice() 
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
      amenities       RECORD;
      paramValues RECORD;
      logsumAccessebility RECORD;
      propertyType   integer;
      unitPrice      float;
      freehold       integer;
      tazId          bigint;
      unit            RECORD;
BEGIN
     FOR unit IN (SELECT * from main2012.fm_unit_res)
LOOP
    amenities := getAmenitiesById(unit.sla_address_id);
    tazId := toBigint(amenities.taz_id);
    logsumAccessebility := getLogsumByTazId(tazId);
    propertyType := getPropertyTypeFromUnitType(unit.unit_type);
    paramValues := getParamValuesByPropertyType(propertyType);
    freehold := 0;
    unitPrice := paramValues.intercept + (paramValues.floor_area * ln(unit.floor_area)) + (paramValues.freehold * freehold) + (paramValues.logsum_accessebility * logsumAccessebility.accessibility);
    UPDATE main2012.fm_unit_res SET rent = unitPrice WHERE fm_unit_id = unit.fm_unit_id;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I run the function I am getting an error like this:

```
    ERROR: record "paramvalues" is not assigned yet
    SQL state: 55000
    Detail: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.

Context: PL/pgSQL function calculateunitprice() line 20 at assignment
```

Please give me your ideas. Am I doing anything wrong here (syntax) or is there a limit in the number of records I can initialize within a stored procedure?

Comment: maybe cos you assign `hparamValues :=` instead of `paramValues :=`? :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VaoTsun. Sorry, it was a typing mistake. It is not the problem. I have corrected it in the question.

Comment: add `raise info '%',getPropertyTypeFromUnitType(unit.unit_type);raise info '%',getPropertyTypeFromUnitType(unit.unit_type);` before declaring `paramValues`, then run function and tell the last value of raised info before error?..

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun. The last value before error was 0 which explains that no paramValues were selected. I have to rewrite the function to handle this I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the output, by adding

`raise info '%',getPropertyTypeFromUnitType(unit.unit_type);
raise info '%',getPropertyTypeFromUnitType(unit.unit_type);`
before declaring `paramValues`